# How do I use specific css to taxonomy-term in teaser?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

On the front page a list of teasers is shown for different content types. For one of these content types I want to use different css depending on the value of the taxonomy term.

- Content type name : "messages"
- taxonomy values in list "type": offer,    want, general
- I want a different background color for "messages"    depending on
  the value of the taxonomy term "type".

In a view for just this content type I could add a CSS-class to the taxonomy field.
But the front page view shows different content types, so teasers are shown, not a list of fields.

How could I change the css-class depending on that particular taxonomy field ? (for the field only of for the entire teaser)

Where to start ?

Comment: Did you try hook_preprocess_HOOK? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/9.0.x

Comment: That would require some programming. I am not sure if I know enough - I'll have to study :) and give it a try.